# < operator in Go lang

Tags: go

Well I am a newby in Go lang, but this doesn't make sense to me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var rectLen, rectWidth float64 = 0, 0

func init() {
    fmt.Println("init is initialized")
    if rectLen < 0 {
        log.Fatal("rectLen smaller than 0")
    }
    if rectWidth < 0 {
        log.Fatal("rectWidht smaller than 0")
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main is initialized")
    fmt.Println(rectLen, rectWidth )
}
```

This will print out:

```
init is initialized
Main is initialized
0 0
```

Why is 0 and 0 printed out when my init function is "guarding" that my rectLen, rectWidth variables should be strictly greater than 0?
If I change the values to something less than 0, it works fine, I get:

```
init is initialized
2009/11/10 23:00:00 rectLen smaller than 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Because `<` is not the same as “equal to”.  Try changing your operators to `<=`. This should fire only if your value is less than OR equal to 0

Comment: Yep, I am dumb. Thanks! :))

Comment: @AndreiB  you’re not dumb, your just new. I’ve been programming for 17 years and still make mistakes and google-fu everyday. !   Hang in there

Comment: The day we programmers stop making programming mistakes is the day we stop programming :)

Comment: Wow...I didn't expect such kind words.